# Laravel Yajra Datatables Hide Null Column

Tags: laravel-7, laravel-datatables

Wha is the best way to `hide empty` or `null comumns` from `Yajra Datatables`:

```
var table = $('.data-table').DataTable({

      processing: true,

      serverSide: true,

      ajax: "{{ route('any.route') }}",

      columns: [

          // How to Hide any of these columns if its data is empty or null?
          // for exampe I want to hide mname column ?
          // visible: what condition for example !!!!
          {data: 'fname', name: 'fname'},
          {data: 'mname', name: 'mname'},
          {data: 'lname', name: 'lname'},
          ....
      ]

  });
```

How do I hide `th` in `table` whenever any data is `empty or null`. for instance, using `visible:`, what condition should I use to test if the `data:` is `empty` or `null`

Answer (score 1):

Can I see your controller? 
 I have same issue but I can fix it 
**Try this in your controller!**

```
public function example(){
if ($request->ajax()) { // if request ajax
    $data = User::all();  //  take all user table
    return Datatables::of($data)
        ->editColumn('fname', function ($row) {  //this example  for edit your columns if colums is empty 
            $fname = !empty($row->name) ? $row->name : 'empty';
            return $fname;
        })
        ->make(true);
    return view('example', compact('data'));
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to hide NULL values from the data tables.

```
  $('#leads').DataTable({
    
      "columnDefs": [{
        "defaultContent": "-",
        "targets": "_all"
    }]
```